# Built in PHP Classes

Tags: php, class, oop, documentation

I want to learn OOP PHP, and I think I need to know all predefined classes of PHP. However I cannot find any website that has list of them. On php.net i only find functions and there are examples of doing it oop or procedural way. Does anybody know where should I find those classes? Big thanks for replies

Comment: You don't need to do that. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-achieve-php-proficiency?page=1

Comment: php.net doesn't provide a list of all built-in classes, in the same way it doesn't provide a list of all built-in functions.... because it's all broken down by categories, and each is detailed within those categories

Comment: But learning OOP PHP doesn't require you to know every single built-in class, in the same way that learning procedural PHP doesn't require you to know every single built-in function

Comment: Mark ty for the laracasts, already subscribed :-) I thought there are only lets say 10-15 classes built in... Anyway, thanks again for the laracasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php

Note that this doesn't output interfaces, but there is also a function for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-interfaces.php

Remember that this will give you all classes of extensions that are currently installed, as only these are available. It will not include classes or interfaces that are available in extensions that are not installed.

However, learning OOP is independent from knowing all existing classes. If you want to do something concrete, like accessing the file system, I'd think it appropriate to then read about file system classes and their OOP interface, but it would be useless to read about the Memcache class if you don't want to use Memcache. Most of the time in OOP you create your own classes and program the business logic of the application - you will encounter built-in classes very rarely, because usually you'd add a wrapping or isolating layer around their results pretty soon, and then pass these (your own) objects around.

Comment: ty for the great reply. I have seen many tutorials, where they use built in Mysql class, so my thoughts were that i should at least know what other classes are :-)

Comment: PHP 5.6 knows about 143 classes and 16 interfaces, PHP 7.0 has 153 classes and 18 interfaces. It's a lot of stuff, and even though I am an experienced developer, I never memorize them in my brain - that's what documentation is for if I need to use something. It is worth getting a general picture about what PHP offers in case you need it.

Comment: and one more question, is there a way to get properties and methods of a class? Like... i want to browse the structure of lets say MYSQLI class... is there any way to do it?